# How to determine whether a printer supports bidirectional communication, or not

Tags: windows, visual-c++, printing, com, driver

I am using the `Print Spooler API` to automate some printer management tasks; currently I work on certain functionality that requires bidirectional communication, which is not a problem (sending BIDI requests and reading output data works as expected) but before trying to do a request, I would like to assure that BIDI communication is supported by the acual device (to avoid any COM exceptions).

The documentation about `Print Spooler Components` explains, that both the application and the driver must implement the `bidirectional communication interfaces`; of course I did that for my application (otherwise no requests can be send), but the driver is usually provided by a third-party. Furthermore the print provider DLL must implement the `SendRecvBidiData` function...

Since the `Enable bidirectional communication` option is available for any printer (via printer properties dialog), I assume it must be possible to easily query this information from the system (in case of the feature is not supported the checkbox is disabled, for instance).

I already checked the various `DRIVER_INFO_X` and `PRINTER_INFO_X` structures, but none of them contain a BIDI flag, or such... I also had the idea that this information might be inferred from the driver itself.

Is there a way to determine if the driver implements the required interfaces, or any other solution that allows to infer whether the driver supports bidirectional communication, or not?

Comment: there is a `enableBIDI` proptery in win32_printer WMI class ...

Comment: I would like to avoid usage of `WMI`. I prefer Windows API functions whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Attributes member on PRINTER_INFO_2, there is an undocumented entry:

`PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_BIDI       0x00000800`

Comment: Might work for some scenarios... I can imply that bidirectional communication is supported by the driver, if the flag is set, but what if not?